# How to modify tidb default GLOBAL variables like "tidb_replica_read" value in TiDB

Tags: distributed-database, tidb

Concept: https://pingcap.com/docs/dev/follower-read/

For detailing, i have also asked the question in here: https://github.com/pingcap/tidb/issues/17650

While getting value of `tidb_replica_read` config param, it shows "leader" by DEFAULT. Document of pingcap (link at top) says that it can be set using session variable. How can i change globally. I am unable to find a **my.cnf** type file neither any appropriate section in TiDB config: https://github.com/pingcap/tidb/blob/master/config/config.toml.example

Can someone help if this is possible with existing TiDB support?

PS: i already tried

```
set @@global.tidb_replica_read='follower';
```

It threw error: **ERROR 1105 (HY000): Variable 'tidb_replica_read' is a SESSION variable and can't be used with SET GLOBAL**

Comment: Do you want to deploy TiDB across multiple regions/data-centers?

Comment: yes @shenli3514

Comment: removed "accept". 
Answer got edited afterwards. Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with AndreMouche, this is not supported as of now

Edit: My PR was merged recently - https://github.com/pingcap/tidb/pull/27622. You can expect this feature in next release

Answer (score 1):

According to the issue https://github.com/pingcap/tidb/issues/17650, I think the TiDB doesn't support this feature while the TiDB community is already working on this feature